# What happens if more than 100 users try to connect to Firebase spark plan

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging scheme to send notifications to clients. The Number of audience to my app is nearly 2000 and all of them might have active internet connection all the time

Ii need to know what happens if such case occurs ie. all 2000 devices are online.

If I send a notification,how many of them will be able to retrieve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need to do is send notifications, not connect to Firebase Database or Storage, use is free and unlimited.

From the [Firebase Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) page:

**Included Free**

> Analytics, App Indexing, Authentication, Cloud
>   Messaging, Crash Reporting, Dynamic Links, Invites, *Notifications* &
>   Remote Config

Further discussion at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38129284/4815718).

Answer (score 5):

You are specifically referring to the limit on Database connections imposed by the free plan. However, that does not limit FCM messages in any way (they are unlimited). All users will therefore be able to receive the messages.

Database connections represent the number of open socket connections to your Realtime Database. This is essentially one per client app (mobile device or browser tab connected to the Database).

Comment: what will happen if more then 100 database clients are connected as it gives only 100 users for free tire

Comment: The concurrent limit on DB connections has no impact on FCM message delivery. Entirely separate.