# FireCloud messaging and a RealTime Weather Alert app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am planning to use Google's FCM messaging for sending Real Time Alerts to my Tsunami Alerter app.

Wanted to know whether if there are 100,000 users of my app they would be able to receive instant alerts within say 3-5 minutes? (I heard FCM has limits) but I am still not able to comprehend what are those limits are!

Can anyone please explain me further? (100,000 messages to 100,000 different users within 5 minutes)

Whether Parallel connections limit like 1000 users will come into picture if I use a Free Plan?

Comment: And what are these limits you have heard that you are concerned with?

Comment: Something like 10000 messages and the other 2 plans like Blaze and another one doesn't have any?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129284/is-gcm-now-fcm-free-for-any-limit (I am not sure about paraller connections either)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone please explain me further? (100,000 messages to 100,000 different users within 5 minutes)

Typically you get a push message within seconds but of course there are other factors such as internet connection and device power profiles.

> Whether Parallel connections limit like 1000 users will come into picture if I use a Free Plan?

There is no such thing as a "Free Plan" since FCM is free. Other Firebase services you have to pay for.

All the 1000 connections thing means is that you can send a max of 1000 messages in a single request so you have to split them up

Comment: So for sending 100,000 messages I need to send 100 different requests? my concern is more about message reaching the people within say 5 minutes not sure what would happen..

Comment: thats right you split them up, and as I said typically they get them within seconds, most factors of users not getting messages within that 5 min is out of your control. You will have to build in extra logic to your app/server if you are that concerned about people getting messages such as recording if a user got the message or not but thats outside the scope of this question