# FCM free version Usage limits

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I`m considering FCM to push message and have a fairly large user base, 1-2 million users using in a week. I have the following queries on the free FCM usage

1. The number of calls to firebase per day/week/month, is it unlimited in the free FCM usage?
2. Is there a limit on the concurrent calls I can make to my FCM server account?
3. Can the data payload exceed 4kb?
4. Is there a limit on the device groups that can be created?

Comment: Also posted on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/ktzPsTfJbx4

Comment: These are great questions but not really appropriate for this forum.  would reach out to Firebase support directly to start a dialog. *Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic* Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

1. Firebase Cloud Messaging is indeed free and unlimited. There is no documented limit on the number of calls you can make, although there are measures to protect against abuse.
2. Not that I know of.
3. Nope, the maximum message size is 4k.
4. There is no limit on the number of device groups that can be created (at least as far as I know).

Comment: Thanx for the quick response,  further refering on (2) there is a limit of a 100 DB connections allowed in the spark plan, would dis map to the concurrent calls allowed   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129284/is-gcm-now-fcm-free-for-any-limit

Comment: That's for the Firebase Database. It has nothing to do with Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Sure, in cloud messaging the tokens generated for the client devices(unlimited) would be stored differently? also I`l trying to integrate the Admin SDK and have a concern on the tokens.

Comment: Firebase device registration token same for different apps on the same device?