# Does FCM push notification has limitation of deliverying to every targeted devices when targeted device is more than 1000?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've developed API which sending push notification to all targeted device with the help of google-services.json and token for Firebase cloud messaging (FCM).
But when I'm trying to send push notification to more than 1000 devices, it's hardly delivered 40-50% only.

I'd tried out to find RCA but not found anything, Since got message as sent successfully from gateway (FCM) after submitting all the tokens to FCM.
and after that I'm helpless to debug since control is at FCM end.

I've enabled all the necessary conditions for push notification delivery such as notification permission enabled, priority of notification high, internet connectivity proper, battery saver off etc.

Already gone through many links and forums for finding answer of this but come as empty handed.

Can anyone from firebase cloud messaging team explain that, is there any limitation of FCM to delivered push notification to each device when number is larger than 1000?

Comment: may be this link helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129284/is-gcm-now-fcm-free-for-any-limit

Comment: Thanks, this link gives some idea about limitations of FCM.